# Plotting complex numbers

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting an Argand Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-an-argand-diagram)

How do I plot complex numbers in *Mathematica*? The following is a part of my data, the eigen values of a 50 by 50 asymmetric matrix:

```
 2.183, 2.1726 + 0.081626 I, 2.1726 - 0.081626 I, 
 2.14149 + 0.161732 I, 2.14149 - 0.161732 I, 2.09002 + 0.238883 I, 
 2.09002 - 0.238883 I, 2.01881 + 0.311781 I, 2.01881 - 0.311781 I, 
 1.92881 + 0.379272 I, 1.92881 - 0.379272 I, 1.8213 + 0.440343 I, 
 1.8213 - 0.440343 I, 1.69787 + 0.494111 I, 1.69787 - 0.494111 I, 
 1.56041 + 0.539817 I, 1.56041 - 0.539817 I, 1.41104 + 0.57683 I, 
 1.41104 - 0.57683 I, 1.25211 + 0.60465 I, 1.25211 - 0.60465 I
```

I can extract the real and Imaginary parts using the commands with

```
Im[Eigenvalues[mtrx1]]
```

and

```
Re[Eigenvalues[mtrx1]]
```

but then could not see how to pair up the real and imaginary parts in order to make a plot. Please help

Comment: You could plot `Abs` and/or `Re` and/or `Im` on the same plot.

Comment: Alernatively you can pair up the real and imaginary parts with the following: `data=Tranpose[{Re[Eigenvalues[mtrx1]],Im[Eigenvalues[mtrx1]]}]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.Stackexchange ! Consider registering your account. Take a look at a related question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-an-argand-diagram

Comment: Similar: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3458/57

Comment: Asymmetric in what sense? Obviously not skew-symmetric (or, anti-symmetric if your in physics) as the eigenvalues are not purely imaginary, but I'm wondering if the symmetry would be conducive to some other means of plotting.

Answer (score 22):

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + I RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {30}];

p = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ data,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
   ImagePadding -> 40,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]];

Show[p, Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: In the current version, one can just do `ListPlot[ReIm[data]]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have complex numbers and you want to plot them as points in the complex plane, it seems strange, doesn't it, to have to first pull them apart into real and imaginary parts? If you use David Park's *Presentations* add-on, you need not---you may treat complex numbers as such (just like everywhere else in *Mathematica* but in the oddly exceptional case of plotting!):

```
data = {2.183, 2.1726 + 0.081626 I, 2.1726 - 0.081626 I, 
    2.14149 + 0.161732 I, 2.14149 - 0.161732 I, 2.09002 + 0.238883 I, 
    2.09002 - 0.238883 I, 2.01881 + 0.311781 I, 2.01881 - 0.311781 I, 
    1.92881 + 0.379272 I, 1.92881 - 0.379272 I, 1.8213 + 0.440343 I, 
    1.8213 - 0.440343 I, 1.69787 + 0.494111 I, 1.69787 - 0.494111 I, 
    1.56041 + 0.539817 I, 1.56041 - 0.539817 I, 1.41104 + 0.57683 I, 
    1.41104 - 0.57683 I, 1.25211 + 0.60465 I, 1.25211 - 0.60465 I};

<< Presentations`

Draw2D[{PointSize -> Large, Red, ComplexPoint /@ data}, Axes -> True]
```

(Sorry, SE Uploader for the image isn't working due to some kind of Java error.)