# Passing a variable messages list to Quiet

Tags: message-coding

I'm trying to build a Verbose option into some code but I'm having trouble passing to a [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) statement a variable list of which messages I want to suppress.

My naïve try is code along the lines of

```
f[x_] := Module[{messageList},
  messageList = {Power::infy};
  Quiet[1/x, messageList]
  ]
f[0]
```

The idea would then be to build an option `Verbose` which controls whether the assignment `messageList = {Power::infy}` is made, or whether that variable is set to `{}`, which will let the message through.

However, even this bare-bones code is not working, and it returns messages of the sort

```
Quiet::anmlist: Argument 2 of Quiet[1/0,messageList$1303]
      should be All, None, a message name, or a list of message names. >>
```

(though obviously the number after `messageList$` changes every time).

---

#### Edit

It seems, from a discussion in the comments, that two things are important (though I don't understand why). First of all, not all error messages are treated equally (as shown e.g. by running `Evaluate[{Power::infy, FindRoot::lstol}]`) so to give a better example, here is one with the error I'm interested in, [`FindRoot::lstol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/FindRoot/lstol.html):

```
g[a_] := Module[{verbose = True, messageList},
  If[verbose,
   messageList = {},
   messageList = {FindRoot::lstol}
   ];
  Quiet[
   FindRoot[x^2 + x + a, {x, 3}]
   , messageList]
  ]
g[1]
```

It is also important to me to be able to control, from within the function (and eventually with an `OptionsPattern[]` that contains `Verbose->True` or `False`) whether the message list that gets passed is `{}` or a nontrivial one. I'm not picky about how it gets there (i.e. `messageList = If[verbose, {}, {FindRoot::lstol}];` would serve just fine) but it does need to have at least that level of logic built in.

---

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You need to use `Evaluate@messageList` inside `Quiet` because `Quiet` has the attribute `HoldAll`.

Comment: I tried that, but it has very patchy behaviour and different messages work differently. Try, for example, running `Evaluate[{Power::infy, FindRoot::lstol}]`: the first one evaluates to itself, but the second one returns the error message. And, of course, giving `Quiet` the message text is not what you want to do.

Comment: OK, try this: `function[x_] := 
 With[{messageList := {Power::infy, FindRoot::lstol}}, 
  Quiet[1/x, messageList]]` (Worked for me on your example but I don't know what other corner cases there are.)

Comment: @Pickett Unless I am overlooking something, there's no need to use `SetDelayed` inside `With`'s first argument.

Comment: @TeakeNutma You are overlooking the fact that otherwise  `FindRoot::lstol` will be evaluated at assignment. For example `With[{x = 2 + 2}, Hold[x]]` versus `With[{x := 2 + 2}, Hold[x]]`.

Comment: @Pickett That code works on its own, but it breaks down if the assignment of `messageList` contains any logic. Thus, even `messageList := If[True, {FindRoot::lstol}]` inside the `With[{...}` statement returns an error.

Comment: @episanty OK, I like your new example. I think we at least did some ground work for the people who are good at this so that they can write answers. This is a little bit over my head now, though. +1

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help in clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Hold` to prevent message names from being evaluated until the time is right:

```
g[a_, verbose_:False] :=
  Module[{messageList}
  , messageList = If[verbose, {}, Hold[FindRoot::lstol]]
  ; messageList /. _[m___] :> Quiet[FindRoot[x^2 + x + a, {x, 3}], {m}]
  ]
```

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: So, in essence, this works not by Evaluating the `Hold`, but by replacing it with a 'wrapper' that's everything else in the `Quiet`?

Comment: (In that case, I think syntax like `If[verbose, Hold[], Hold[FindRoot::lstol]] /. Hold[m___] :> Quiet[FindRoot[x^2 + x + a, {x, 3}], {m}]` is a bit clearer.)

Comment: @episanty Yes, it works by preventing evaluation of the message list using `Hold` and then transforming the expression into a call to `Quiet`.  Whether or not to use the auxiliary variable `messageList`, or to represent the empty message list using `Hold[]`, are choices that can be made to suit one's taste (and the form of the "real" version of `g`).

Answer (score 5):

Why not something a little simpler?

```
g[a_, verbose_: False] /; ! verbose := Quiet[g[a, True], FindRoot::lstol]
g[a_, True] := FindRoot[x^2 + x + a, {x, 3}]
```

Now:

```
g[1]        (* no message *)

g[1, True]  (* FindRoot::lstol: printed *)
```

This has the advantage of separating the primary definition from the one that controls Message printing, making both easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a workaround which works for my purposes, though it is not particularly pretty, and the weird behaviour of `Evaluate` on error messages remains a mystery to me. It is possible to switch between different `Quiet` behaviours by setting a custom message group and then switching that within the logic.

The following code works, as far as I can tell.

```
$MessageGroups = Join[$MessageGroups, {"Custom" :> {FindRoot::lstol}}]

g[a_, verbose_] := Module[{},
  If[verbose,
   $MessageGroups = ($MessageGroups /. {("Custom" :> {___}) -> ("Custom" :> {})}),
   $MessageGroups = ($MessageGroups /. 
                        {("Custom" :> {___}) -> ("Custom" :> {FindRoot::lstol})})
   ];
  Quiet[
   FindRoot[x^2 + x + a, {x, 3}]
   , {"Custom"}]
  ]
```

It has two obvious disadvantages:

- The function `g` has side effects, and the value of `"Custom"/.$MessageGroups` is depends on the value of `verbose` on the last call to `g`.
- This pollutes a global variable, and may therefore interfere with other uses of `g` run on other notebooks on the same kernel or on parallel kernels.

Both of these can probably be fixed with appropriate use of contexts, though it is probably enough to be careful with both of those disadvantages. In any case, I remain interested in a more 'normal' solution which doesn't need to meddle with normal variables and which explains the different behaviour of `Power::infy` and `FindRoot::lstol`.

Answer (score 1):

### another workaround

example: problem

```
msg = {General::argx, Power::infy}
Quiet[1/0 + Sqrt[], Evaluate@msg]
```

example: workaround

```
msg = {General::argx::English, Power::infy}
Quiet[1/0 + Sqrt[], Evaluate@msg]
```

it seems: messages, which take arguments are problematic