# How can I distribute redefinitions of system functions to parallel kernels?

Tags: packages, parallelization

I'm having some trouble getting my parallel kernels to get wind of user redefinitions of system packages, and I'm looking for the cleanest way to do this - preferably using DistributeDefinitions.

To take an example, suppose I want to [improve](https://xkcd.com/221/) Mathematica's pseudorandom number generator, so I jump in and I redefine it as

```
Unprotect[RandomInteger];
RandomInteger[] = 4 ; (*chosen by fair dice roll.*)
                      (*guaranteed to be random.*)
Protect[RandomInteger];
```

(I actually want to do [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36898/using-nsolve-in-the-complex-plane/57821#57821) in a parallelized environment using the built-in RNG, but it's the same thing.) This works just dandy:

```
Table[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}*)
```

However, if I try to parallelize this, it no longer works as well.

```
ParallelTable[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}*)
```

---

To add on the second part of the structure, I actually want to do this from inside a package ([this one](https://github.com/episanty/EPToolbox), to be specific). So, suppose I write

```
BeginPackage["xkcd`"];
xkcdRandom[] = 4;

Unprotect[RandomInteger];
RandomInteger[] = 4 ;  (*chosen by fair dice roll.*)
                       (*guaranteed to be random.*)
Protect[RandomInteger];
EndPackage[];
```

with `xkcdRandom` put in just to file in `` xkcd` `` as a nonempty context. Doing this, I get

```
Table[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}*)
```

and so far so good, and parallelizing it we have

```
ParallelTable[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}*)
```

as before, but now I can jump in again and say

```
DistributeDefinitions["xkcd`"];
```

and try again, but I still get

```
ParallelTable[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}*)
```

OK, then, so `RandomInteger` is inside the package but it is still part of the `` System` `` context, which is fair enough, but then if I write

```
DistributeDefinitions["System`"]
```

I still get

```
ParallelTable[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}*)
```

and even with an explicit

```
DistributeDefinitions[RandomInteger]
```

it still doesn't work

```
ParallelTable[
 RandomInteger[]
 , {j, 1, 10}]

(*{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}*)
```

---

Now, I know I can simply run my specific redefinition inside a `ParallelEvaluate` command, but ideally I would like to simply have my `.m` file run a `DistributeDefinitions` on my package at the end of the file (after the `End[]` of the package) and forget about it on the user side, which has otherwise worked perfectly. Is there a way to extend that workflow to redefinitions like this one?

Comment: maybe SetSharedVariable