# On the numerical roots of transcendent functions

Tags: equation-solving, algorithm

Writing:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} = {-2, 2, -2, 2, 0, 6, 5} / 6;

h[t_] := (a + b t + Cos[e + f t])^2 + (c + d t + Sin[e + f t])^2 - g^2

sol1 = NSolve[h[t] == 0, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 10][[All, 1, 2]]
```

instantly we get:

> {-0.1995415116, 0.6420342510, 3.052979574, 4.390122149}

which are **all real roots** of this function as graphically verifiable:

```
Plot[h[t], {t, -25, 25}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "h[t]"}]
```

[image]

The best I can do to emulate `NSolve[]` is to apply the *Bolzano's theorem* coupled with the *Newton-Raphson method*:

```
sol2 = {};

T = 5;
dt = 10^-1;
tol = 10^-10;

ti = -T;
tf = -T + dt;

While[tf < T,
      If[h[ti] h[tf] < tol,
         t0 = (ti + tf) / 2.;
         While[Abs[h[t0] / h'[t0]] > tol,
               t0 = t0 - h[t0] / h'[t0]
              ];
         sol2 = Join[sol2, {t0}]
        ];
      ti = tf;
      tf = tf + dt
     ]

sol1 == sol2
```

> True

but it's evident that all depends heavily on the choice of parameters `0 < dt < T`.

The question is therefore how to improve this approach or what other methods I could apply automatically to have the same solutions of `NSolve[]`, as far as possible of course, I understand well that *Mathematica algorithms* will always be better than my "toys".

---

**Addendum**

I was very fascinated by the methods suggested in the comments by *@Michael E2*. While the "graphical methods" are linked to the `Plot[]` functions implemented internally to *Mathematica*, the "spectral methods" are potentially exportable in less advanced spreadsheets.

In particular, aware of my limitations and without any pretense, implementing the *Chebyshev-proxy rootfinder algorithm* in the following way, the idea is to generate the coefficients of a polynomial that in a given interval has the same real roots as the assigned transcendent function, easily computable, for example, with *Aberth-Ehrlich method*, then adjust with the evergreen *Newton-Raphson method*:

```
(*Roots search range and tolerance*)
{tmin, tmax} = {-5, 5};
tol = 10^-10;

n = 10;
While[True,

      (*Calculate Chebyshev's nodes*)
      chebnodes = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
      For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,            
          ti = Cos[Pi (i - 1) / n] (tmax - tmin) / 2 + (tmax + tmin) / 2.;
          chebnodes[[i]] = h[ti]
         ];

      (*Calculate Chebyshev's coefficients*)
      chebcoeff = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
      For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
          sum = 0;
          For[j = 2, j <= n, j++,
              sum = sum + Cos[Pi (i - 1) (j - 1) / n] chebnodes[[j]];
             ];                   
          chebcoeff[[i]] = (chebnodes[[1]] + 2 sum + (-1)^(i-1) chebnodes[[n+1]])/n
         ];
      chebcoeff[[1]] = chebcoeff[[1]] / 2;
      chebcoeff[[n + 1]] = chebcoeff[[n + 1]] / 2;
  
      (*Calculate error*)
      err = 0;
      For[i = 2 + n/2, i <= n + 1, i++,
          err = err + Abs[chebcoeff[[i]]]
         ];
       
      (*Check if it's necessary to double the nodes*)
      If[err > tol, n = 2 n, Break[]]
     ];

(*Calculate coefficients of resolving polynomial*)
polycoeff = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
    k = i;
    For[j = 1, j <= (5 + 2 (n - i) - (-1)^(n + i)) / 4, j++,
        If[i == 1,
           l = 1,
           l = 2^i (i + 2 j - 3) (i + j - 3)! / (4 (i - 1)! (j - 1)!)
          ];
        polycoeff[[i]] = polycoeff[[i]] - (-1)^(n + j) l chebcoeff[[k]];
        k = k + 2
       ]
   ];

(*Calculate polynomial's roots with Aberth-Ehrlich method*)
poly = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
    poly = poly + polycoeff[[i]] t^(i - 1)
   ];
polyroots = {ToRules[NRoots[poly == 0, t, Method -> "Aberth"]]}[[All, 1, 2]];

(*Select real roots within the interval*)
sol = ConstantArray[0, Length[polyroots]];
nsol = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[polyroots], i++,
    If[-1.001 < Re[polyroots[[i]]] < 1.001 && Abs[Im[polyroots[[i]]]] < 10^-15,
       nsol = nsol + 1;
       sol[[nsol]] = polyroots[[i]] (tmax - tmin) / 2 + (tmax + tmin) / 2
      ]
   ];

(*Roots adjustment with Newton-Raphson method*)
sol3 = ConstantArray[0, nsol];
For[i = 1, i <= nsol, i++,
    t0 = sol[[i]];
    While[Abs[h[t0] / h'[t0]] > tol,
          t0 = t0 - h[t0] / h'[t0]
         ];
    sol3[[i]] = t0
   ];

sol1 == sol3
```

> True

It's undoubtedly a "toy code", from which, however, I had (and maybe others will have in the future) interesting ideas, most likely new notions compared to the classic "lessons for engineers".

Comment: Related: spectral methods such as [`chebRoots[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86860/find-all-roots-of-a-function-with-parabolic-cylinder-functions-in-a-range-of-the/113950#113950) and graphical methods such as [`FindAllCrossings[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/5666#5666).

Comment: Is this question asking how `NSolve` works? Or do you have a specific use-case where it doesn't work, and you'd like help developing an approach for that? As far as I'm concerned, if `NSolve` can do it usually it means that anything you try won't be as good, so why even bother?

Answer (score 1):

`NSolve` for a given range of `t` solves your problem:

```
 NSolve[{h[t] == 0, -10 < t < 10}, t]
 (*{{t -> -0.199542}, {t -> 0.642034}, {t -> 3.05298}, {t -> 4.39012}}*)
```