# Finding the roots of Abs[Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2 x)/I), 1.5, I]]=0

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I want to solve for the first 100 or more zeros of ***Abs[Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2 x)/I), 1.5, I]]=0***;

The following code is my simple attempt：

```
a = 2000;
Quiet@FindRoot[Abs[Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 1.5, I]] == 0, {x, #, 0, a}] & /@ Range[a] //Values//Flatten//Round[#, 0.001]&//Sort//DeleteDuplicates
```

But I lose some roots when solving for more roots.

How can I precisely find more roots.

Comment: This code, which is essentially the same as yours, gives me all the roots: `Quiet@FindRoot[Abs[Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 1.5, I]] == 0, {x, #, 0, a}] & /@ Range[1, a, 20] // Values // Flatten // Union[#, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2]/Abs[#1] < 10^(-3) &)] &`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Approximating a function with a Chebyshev interpolation is a powerful way to find roots.  See links at the beginning of the code dump.  Best to use an analytic function with this method (i.e., drop `Abs`, which is not differentiable).  Takes about 5 sec. to find `cc` and `rts50`.

```
cc = adaptiveChebSeries[
   x |-> Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 15/10, I], 1, 20000, 
   "Points" -> 2^8, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
Length@cc
(*  130  *)

rts50 = chebRoots[cc, {1, 20000}];
Length@rts50
(*  63  *)

ReImPlot[
 Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 15/10, I], {x, 1, 20000}, 
 Mesh -> {rts50}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Automatic}]
```

[image]

**Code dump**

Code taken from [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113950/4999); see [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83966/roots-of-whittaker-w-function/113801#113801) for a discussion of the code.

```
(* Chebyshev extreme points *)
chx[n_, prec_: MachinePrecision] := N[Cos[Range[0, n]/n Pi], prec];

(* Chebyshev series approximation to f *)
Clear[chebSeries];
chebSeries[f_, a_, b_, n_, prec_: MachinePrecision] := Module[{x, y, cc},
   x = Rescale[chx[n, prec], {-1, 1}, {a, b}];
   y = f /@ x;                       (* function values at Chebyshev points *)
   cc = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[y, 1];  (* get coeffs from values *)
   cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;               (* adjust first & last coeffs *)
   cc
   ];

(* recursively double the Chebyshev points 
* until the PrecisionGoal is met 
* The function values are memoized in f0
* *)
Clear[adaptiveChebSeries];
Options[adaptiveChebSeries] = {PrecisionGoal -> 14, "Points" -> 32, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, MaxIterations -> 5};
adaptiveChebSeries[f_, a_, b_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{cc, f0, max, len = 0, sum},
  f0[x_] := f0[x] = f[x];  (* values reused in subsequent series *)
  NestWhile[
   (cc = chebSeries[f0, a, b, #, OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]];
     (* check error estimate *)
     max = Max@Abs@cc;     (* sum the tail of the series *)
     sum = 0;              (* relative to the max coefficient *)
     len = LengthWhile[
       Reverse@cc, (sum += Abs@#) < 10^-OptionValue[PrecisionGoal]*max &];
     2 #) &,               (* double the number of points *)
   OptionValue["Points"],
   len < 3 && # <= 2^OptionValue[MaxIterations] OptionValue["Points"] &
                           (* at least two coefficients dropped *)
   ];
  If[len < 3, 
   Message[adaptiveChebSeries::cvmit, OptionValue[MaxIterations]]];
  If[TrueQ[len > 1], Drop[cc, 1 - len], cc]
  ]

(* "Chebyshev companion matrix" (Boyd, 2014) /
 "Colleague matrix" (Good, 1961) *)
colleagueMatrix[cc_] := With[{n = Length[cc] - 1},
   SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 :> 1/2,
      {i_, j_} /; i + 1 == j :> 1/(2 - Boole[i == 1])}, {n, n}] - 
    SparseArray[{{n, i_} :> cc[[i]]/(2 cc[[n + 1]])}, {n, n}]
   ];

(* Find the real roots of a truncated Chebyshev series
 representing a function over an interval [a,b] *)
Options[chebRoots] = {(* TBD *)};
chebRoots::usage = 
  "chebRoots[c,{a,b}], c = {c0, c1,..., cn} Chebyshev coefficients, over the interval {a,b}
  computes the (real) roots in the interval {a,b}";
chebRoots[coeff_, dom_: {-1, 1}, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{eigs},
  eigs = Eigenvalues@colleagueMatrix[coeff];
  roots = Sort@Rescale[
     Re@Select[
       eigs,
       Abs[Im[#]] < 1*^-15 &&          (*  Im error tolerance *)
         -1.0001 < Re[#] < 1.0001 &],  (* Re error tolerance *)
     {-1, 1}, dom]
  ]
```

Comment: such a beauty!!!

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Abs[Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 3/2, I]];

sol[n_Integer?Positive] := sol[n] = Quiet@Select[(FindRoot[
             f[x] == 0, {x, #, 2000 (n - 1), 2000 n},
             WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@ Range[2000 (n - 1), 2000 n, 5]) // 
         Values // Flatten, Abs[f[#]] < 10^-10 &] // Round[#, 0.001] & // 
    Sort // DeleteDuplicates
```

The next expression is quite slow to evaluate

```
len = Length /@ (sol /@ Range[10])

(* {20, 8, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3} *)
```

The cumulative number of roots is

```
Accumulate[len]

(* {20, 28, 34, 40, 45, 49, 53, 56, 60, 63} *)

plt[n_Integer?Positive] := plt[n] =
  Plot[f[x], {x, 2000 (n - 1), 2000 n},
   PlotPoints -> 200,
   MaxRecursion -> 10,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
     Point[{#, 0} & /@ sol[n]]}]

plt[1]
```

[image]

```
plt[10]
```

[image]

The roots get progressively further apart as `x` increases. Even out to `x = 20,000` there are only `63` total roots.

Answer (score 4):

Since from the plot, the roots are apparently almost periodic with slowly growing period, we can use the gap between a roots and the previous to guess the location of the next.  This is essentially a refinement of the OP's approach, refining it by a more judicious choice of starting points.

```
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity, foo};
rts = Re@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Values@NestList[
        {Last@#, 
          foo = 
           FindRoot[
            Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 15/10, 
             I], {x, (x /. #) . {-1, 2} // Re}, 
            WorkingPrecision -> 32]} &,
        NSolve[
         Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (3 - (2*x)/I), 15/10, I] == 0 && 
          2 < Re@x < 20 && -1/4096 < Im@x < 1/4096, {x}],
        100
        ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {30.4636, Null}  *)

N@rts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In hindsight (you need only, say, 20 roots to get this hindsight), you could improve the guess slightly by using

```
(x /. #) . {-1, 2} + 9.869605623855932` // Re
```

for the initial guess for `x` in `FindRoot`.  It saves about 40% on the execution time for 100 roots, and it's certainly worth doing if you want more roots than that.  This hindsight comes from

```
Differences[N@rts[[;; 20]], 2]
(*  {..., 9.869605623855932`} *)
```

You can save a little more time (2-3%) using `Last@Differences[N@rts, 2]`, but you have to spend 30 seconds to compute 100 roots; whereas, computing the first 20 roots takes only `0.35` sec.  FWIW, in case you can use it and since I've computed it, the 100th 2nd-difference is

```
9.869604402607365`
```

Comment: Also, very nice and a (+1), but the Chebyshev interpolation has a special place in my heart. Sorry...

Comment: Your method is very good, but a slight change to the parameters will generate an error message. If I change a function, such as fx = Hypergeometric1F1[
  1 + (-2 (2 - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x]) - 
      4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x])/(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-x]), 2, 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-x]], which part of the program should I adjust?

Comment: @lucky `NSolve` doesn't seem to work to get the roots started. Also the first two roots are too close, before the periodicity begins to show up. I'm afraid this approach will require tweaking for each functions. Try this: `rts = Re@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Values@Prepend[NestList[{Last@#, FindRoot[f[x], {x, (9.87 + x /. #[[;; 2]]) . {-1, 2} // Re}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]} &, FindRoot[f[x], {x, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 32] & /@ {16.5, 41}, 20], FindRoot[f[x], {x, 2.4}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 3):

Your function is very similar, and asymptotically equal, to $g(x)=\frac{e^{i/2} \sin \sqrt{2x}}{\sqrt{2x}}$:

```
f[x_] = Hypergeometric1F1[(3 + 2 I x)/4, 3/2, I];
g[x_] = E^(I/2) Sinc[Sqrt[2 x]];

ReImPlot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 300}]
```

[image]

This means that the zeros of $|f(x)|$ are close to the zeros of $|g(x)|$, which are at $\sqrt{2x_n}=n\pi$, or $x_n=\frac12n^2\pi^2$. Use these as starting points for `FindRoot`:

```
Clear[z];
z[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  z[n] = x /. FindRoot[Abs[f[x]] == 0, {x, n^2*π^2/2}]

z[1]
(*    4.79291    *)

z[2]
(*    19.579    *)

z[1000]
(*    4.9348*10^6    *)
```

Actually, $e^{-i/2} f(x)$ is a real-valued function, so we can look for its roots more easily (because it has zero crossings, instead of the infinitely sharp kinks of $|f(x)|$:

```
Clear[z];
z[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  z[n] = x /. FindRoot[Re[E^(-I/2) f[x]] == 0, {x, n^2*π^2/2}]
```

Faster and no warnings:

```
z[1]
(*    4.79291    *)

z[2]
(*    19.579    *)

z[1000]
(*    4.9348*10^6    *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to ask if there is asymptotically equal for `Hypergeotric1F1[a,b,c]`.

Comment: That would be a question for the [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com). Maybe you can find something on the [functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/).