# How can I output all zero-point data by graphing?

Tags: special-functions

How can I output all zero-point data by graphing?

```
f[x_] := Hypergeometric1F1[
   1 + (-2 (2 - 2 Sqrt[2 x]) - 4 Sqrt[2 x])/(4 Sqrt[2 (-x)]), 2, 
   10 Sqrt[2 (-x)] ];
Plot[Re[f[x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

For example, in *Hypergeometric1F1* above, by means of graphing we can check the correctness of the number of zeros found.

A preliminary test was performed by finding roots using a Chebyshev interpolation approximation function proposed by @Michael E2 ([Roots of Whittaker W function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83966/roots-of-whittaker-w-function/113801#113801)), but still some roots were found to be missing by means of image comparison.

The following roots are solved using this method in the range 0 to 10:

```
{1.0532206155051356002759022212, 2.3823251868867552411190096851,
4.1175783163878905360582608336, 6.2547713021241303166777811106, 
8.7917386732691205358036514888}
```

We can see by the image that there is obviously another root between 3.9 and 4, and similar situation exists in other positions. Is there any good way to solve this problem? Or is there a way to output the information about the zero point through the image?

Comment: `f[x_] = Hypergeometric1F1[
   1 + (-2 (2 - 2 Sqrt[2 x]) - 4 Sqrt[2 x])/(4 Sqrt[2 (-x)]), 2, 
   10 Sqrt[2 (-x)]];
Plot[Re[f[x]], {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_] = Hypergeometric1F1[    1 + (-2 (2 - 2 Sqrt[2 x]) - 4 Sqrt[2 x])/(4 Sqrt[2 (-x)]), 2,     10 Sqrt[2 (-x)]];
plot=Plot[Re[f[x]], {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},   MeshStyle -> Red, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}];
list = Cases[plot, Point[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]];
pts = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[p__] :> p, Infinity][[1]][[list]];
roots=Sort@pts[[;; , 1]]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just now, I used **Re** to process the result is not accurate enough, if I use **Abs** to process the plot to find the zero point, does the program need to be improved?
For example，
`f[x_] = Abs[
   Hypergeometric1F1[
    1 + (-2 (2 - 2 Sqrt[2 x]) - 4 Sqrt[2 x])/(4 Sqrt[2 (-x)]), 2, 
    10 Sqrt[2 (-x)]]];`

Comment: @lucky Yes,this method can not work if the curves does not crossing the x-axis.  I think we can use both `Im` and `Re` or `ReIm` instead of `Abs` will make this ease to handle.

Comment: After testing there is one more question I would like to ask you, I use different ranges to observe the roots, if I use a small range of 0-10, the data is accurate, but if I extend the range to 0-2000, some data will be missing. Consider that we are using plotting. But the reasons for this situation and its solution are not considered clearly.

Comment: @lucky  We can add `PlotPoints->100,MaxRecursion->4` etc.

Answer (score 5):

You might analyse the plot using `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``

```
pic = Plot[{Re[f[x]], 0}, {x, 0, 10}]    
np = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pic[[All, 1]]]; 

(*{{0.0493613, 8.13152*10^-20}, {0.141112, 0.}, {0.444084,4.33681*10^-19}, 
{1.05335,0.}, {1.23352, -3.48029*10^-17}, {2.38238, 0.}, 
{2.41799,2.98407*10^-15},{3.99724,0.}, {4.11752, -5.96311*10^-17}, {5.97122,0.}, 
{6.25477,2.32556*10^-15}, {8.34004, 0.}, {8.79169, -6.58382*10^-17}}*)

Show[{pic, Graphics[{Red, Point[np]}]}]
```

[image]