# Finding the zeros of a non linear complex function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, complex

I need to find the roots of a nonlinear function, namely:

```
F[z_] = 2 E^(2 I b z)
z ((-1 + E^(2 I a Sqrt[z^2 - Subscript[V, 0]])) z + (1 + E^(
    2 I a Sqrt[z^2 - Subscript[V, 0]])) Sqrt[
  z^2 - Subscript[V, 0]]) + (E^(2 I a z) - E^(2 I b z)) (-1 + E^(
 2 I a Sqrt[z^2 - Subscript[V, 0]])) Subscript[V, 0]
```

where:

$\omega$ is complex valued and $a,V_{0}, b$ are real parameters.

I've been trying to solve numerically this problem by defining a new function

```
G[x_, y_] := Module[{Z}, Z = x + I*y; Abs[N[1/F[Z]]]]
```

making a contour plot of this and then approximating the roots by `FindRoot`

```
ContourPlot[G[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -4, 4},PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Mesh -> False, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

but it's not giving me the better graphical quality that I need. Is there any better way to evaluate these complex roots?

Comment: Note that using `Abs[..]` as the function in `ContourPlot[]` [presents difficulties](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/how-to-plot-the-contour-of-fx-y-0-if-always-fx-y-0). Try plotting `Evaluate@Thread[ReIm[F[x + I y]] == 0]`.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `G` deals with the reciprocal of `F`, but taking `F` as the function whose roots are desired, as indicated in the first sentence, I get this:

```
Block[{b = 1, Subscript, a = 1},
 Subscript[V, 0] = 1;
 NSolve[F[z] == 0 && -10 < Re[z] < 10 && -4 < Im@z < 4, z]
 ]
(*
  {{z -> -9.16236 + 2.93903 I}, {z -> -5.94891 + 2.52432 I},
   {z -> -2.66633 + 1.75482 I}, {z -> 2.66633 + 1.75482 I},
   {z -> 5.94891 + 2.52432 I}, {z -> 9.16236 + 2.93903 I}}
*)
```

Plot:

```
Block[{b = 1, Subscript, a = 1},
 Subscript[V, 0] = 1;
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@Thread[ReIm[F[x + I y]] == 0], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 3]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely! Just one more question., do you have any idea about how could I make a graph of this this function? @MichaelE2

Comment: @WaynerKlën See my update.  See if that is what you want.

Comment: What do the lines represent?

Comment: @WaynerKlën `Re@F[z] == 0` and `Im[F[z]] == 0`.  Look up `ReIm` in the docs (unless you have an old version of *Mma*).  Perhaps you'd like a plot of several contours? If so, which ones? The traditional ones are the real part, imaginary part, absolute value (modulus), and argument.  Just apply the appropriate function to `F[x + y I]` and omit the equality `== 0`

Comment: What does each axis mean? Would it be the x axis real part of $\omega$ and the y axis the imaginary part of $\omega$?

Comment: They are the axes of the argument `x + I y` in `F[x + I y]]`, which would be real and imaginary parts of `z = x + I y`.  The OP does not say how $\omega$ is related to the code, but if it is the same as `z`, then the answer to your 2nd question is yes.

Comment: Yeah @MichaelE2, $z=\omega$, but if the both axes are related to the argunments of $z$ the graph of this function shouldn't be a 3-dimensional obejct?Just to clarify my mind.

Comment: @WaynerKlën, most generally the equation `w = F[z]`, with `z` and `w` complex, defines a surface in ${\bf R}^4 = {\bf C}^2$, which cannot be plotted (easily) on a screen. The plot in my answer plots two curves, `Re[F[x + I y]] == 0` and `Im[F[x + I y]] == 0`; the intersections are where `F == 0`.  Perhaps you're looking for something like `Plot3D[Abs[F[x + I y]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -4, 4}]`? There are various ways for trying to visualize complex functions. (P.S. I just realized I forgot to convert my plot code back to `Subscript[V, 0]`.)

Comment: Your Answer was very good, but I need to justify why this plot represents  something acceptable. I just didn't understand one thing: It looks like to me that you take $F(z)==constant$ and made the plot, this way I can figure that plot, is this it?

Comment: @WaynerKlën Yes, but for a nonzero $constant$, I would write it as $F(z) - constant == 0$ in the code, and use `Evaluate@Thread[ReIm[F[x + I y] - constant] == 0]` for the plot.  (You don't need to do that for `NSolve`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50548/discussion-between-wayner-klen-and-michael-e2).