# How to plot list of numbers in the complex plane?

Tags: plotting, complex

This should have a trivial solution, but how do I plot a list of (complex) numbers in the complex plane? Or, put another way, *why doesn't the code below work?*

I get the error "... is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers."

I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so I'm kinda fumbling in the dark. I've taken the last part of the code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16256/38017).

**EDIT: Rahul found the bug, it's corrected in the code below. However, I only see two points in the resulting plot, instead of the expected four. Why?**

```
k = 2;
S = Sum[Sign[i] x^(n + i), {i, -k, k}];

sol = N[ComplexExpand[FullSimplify[Solve[S == 0, x]]]]
(* {{x -> -1.}, {x -> 1.}, {x -> -0.5 - 0.866025 I}, {x -> -0.5 + 0.866025 I}} *)

p = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@x /. sol,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
   ImagePadding -> 40,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]];

Show[p]
```

Comment: `sol` is not a list of complex numbers. `sol` is a list of *replacement rules*, each of which replaces `x` with a complex number. So you should plot `(x /. sol)` instead of `sol` directly.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @Rahul Hmm, that seemed to help, but I only get a plot of two numbers (instead of the four on the list of replacement rules) - do you have an idea what might be going on?

Comment: You need to account for precedence: `{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (x /. sol)`. `ReplaceAll` has lower precedence than `Map`, so you need some braces here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the expression

```
    {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ x /. sol
```

does not produce the output you seem to think it does, but rather:

```
{-1., 1., -0.5 - 0.866025 I, -0.5 + 0.866025 I}
```

As the 3rd and 4th values are not real, they cannot be used as vertical coordinates at horizontal coordinates 3 and 4.

You *could* use instead:

```
    {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (x /. sol)
(* {{-1., 0}, {1., 0}, {-0.5, -0.866025}, {-0.5, 0.866025}} *)
```

Which would serve as the correct point data for `ListPlot`.

It's easier to do the whole thing in a more direct way, with `Graphics` along with `Point`.

Second, at least since *Mathematica* version 10.1, you have the built-in function `ReIm` to use in place of the `{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@` expression.

Third, it's been a *long* time since one needed to use `Show` like that: omit the semicolon at the end of the graphics expression and get the graphics as direct output.

```
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@ReIm[x /. sol]}, 
        AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
        ImagePadding -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
        FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, this gives the following error: Coordinate $CellContext`ReIm[{-1, 1, -0.5 + Complex[0, -0.5] 1.7320508075688772`, -0.5 + Complex[0, 0.5] 1.7320508075688772`}] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form. What am I doing wrong? (I've got version 10.0)

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: My version doesn't support ReIm. I don't seem to be able to just replace "Point@ReIm[x /. sol]" with "Point@{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ x /. sol" - is this how I should do it? Again, sorry for these probably dumb questions, but I don't really understand the syntax yet.

Comment: @Lovsovs: Note carefully the presence of parentheses around `(x /. sol)` in my comment and in the first half of murray's answer.

Comment: @Rahul Yup, that did it!

Answer (score 3):

V10.1 introduced [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html), which make this kind of plot a little easier to create. Also, since `FullSimplify`, `ComplexExpand` and `N` aren't needed, the code can be reduced to:

```
Module[{k = 2, sum, pts},
  sum = Sum[Sign[i] x^(n + i), {i, -k, k}];
  pts = ReIm /@ Solve[sum == 0, x][[All, 1, 2]];
  Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]},
    PlotRangePadding -> .1,
    Frame -> True]]
```

[image: plot]