# replace the element

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How to replace i  with I and ListPlot the  given below [data][1]

```
  data=  {95.657i,-43.579-93.554i,-45.476-82.428i,-61.525-51.496i,-81.875-89.083i,-48.062-80.504i,-75.112-78.776i,-53.963-83.878i,-58.198-88.545i,-64.045-92.482i,-76.981-87.693i,-29.215-81.336i,-43.189-80.751i,-53.326-79.522i,-41.535-57.876i,-83.006-88.08i,-48.328-98.89i,-20.878-106.57i,-55.511-99.815i,-42.748-89.349i,-32.632-78.125i,-48.227-75.97i,-42.462-79.877i,-65.422-78.092i,-60.149-67.779i,-55.073-6{2.414i,-57.063-73.557i,-57.71-83.178i,-34.673-95.471i,-38.761-82.804i,-46.412-67.365i,-72.901-70.031i,-59.272-87.866i,-51.083-78.176i,-41.288-56.95i,-76.95-87.096i,-30.743-79.782i,-55.063-58.806i,-66.655-100.97i,-44.991-90.034i,-39.618-104.36i,-55.437-91.132i,-44.817-66.42i,-70.592-63.896i,-63.361-98.476i,-56.39-100.91i,-52.186-70.375i,-56.332-82.517i,-62.441-88.094i,-55.606-77.67i,-92.82-89.719i,-34.832-90.026i,-67.227-94.244i,-61.74-110.45i,-39.847-88.944i,-69.284-83.234i,-60.728-99.632i,-54.131-62.132i,-62.585-80.076i,-58.928-88.317i,-70.588-93.588i,-50.125-80.192i,-51.416-86.617i}
```

Comment: To replace try this: `data /. i -> I`. I do not understand, what do you mean by plot.

Comment: Now, I have uploaded more data, where replace rule is not working.

Comment: @GopalVerma Your data is syntactically incorrect because some matching braces `{` are missing or extra in it. That's why the replacement rule does not even have a chance to execute. Fix the braces, and everything works.

Comment: I tried replace is not working. Did you tried?

Comment: It is quite possible you are looking at strings (impossible  to tell from a google drive preview).  In that case you need `StringReplace[string,"i"->"I"]` then use `ToExpression` to convert to numbers.

Comment: Thanks@george , But using this approach  I am not able to  plot the data. Can help to me to plot the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $I = \sqrt{-1}$ than you can use a 'Rule' to substitute $i$. You can write symbols by hitting escape, than writing the name of the symbol, and hitting escape again. (imaginary unit is [ImaginaryI] or 'esc'ii'esc')

Then you might want to look into a ListPlot for complex data. ([Plotting complex numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16252/plotting-complex-numbers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))