# How to plot a sequence of complex numbers?

Tags: plotting, complex

I want to plot the complex sequence of numbers $(1/(1 + I))^n$ so that I can roughly see divergence/convergence.  I tried DiscretePlot but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One example is [plotting-complex-numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16252/plotting-complex-numbers)

Comment: Write the complex sequence in polar form:  $$1/\exp{( n * i * \pi / 4 )} / \sqrt{ 2 }^n \,\,.$$  The sequence spirals around and approaches zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the new in M12 function [`ComplexListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot):

```
ComplexListPlot[Table[(1/(1+I))^n, {n, 10}]]
```

[image]

In earlier versions you can use [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot):

```
ListPlot[Table[ReIm[1/(1+I)^n], {n, 10}]]
```

[image]

If you want a continuous curve, you can use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot):

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[1/(1+I)^n], {n, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to plot this in magnitude and phase:

```
c = Table[(1/(1 + I))^n, {n, 25}];
ListPlot[{Abs[c], Arg[c]}]
```

[image]

You can see the convergence of the magnitude to zero and the phase constantly decreasing with constant slope.