# Plotting Complex Numbers as "Arrows" on the Complex Plane

Tags: plotting, complex

Given the following complex numbers (defined as the values of two functions `f` and `g` defined only on the points `0` and `1`):

```
f[0] := (1 + 0 I)
f[1] := 0.5 E^(I \[Pi]/4)
g[0] := (0 + 1 I)
g[1] := 2 E^(I (\[Pi]/2 + \[Pi]/2 + \[Pi]/2))
```

is there a way to plot each of `f[0]`, `f[1]`, `g[0]`, and `g[0]` as "arrow vectors" on the complex plane? Something analogous to the following:

[image]

except that (i) each of the complex numbers is labeled `f[0]`, `f[1]`, `g[0]`, `g[1]` and (ii) the two `f` complex numbers are colored *green* while the two `g` complex numbers are colored *blue*.

Comment: There are many posts on plotting complex numbers,  e.g. [Plotting complex numbers as an Argand Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram).  And there are many posts on plotting arrows (see e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612)).  If you read both your question will be slightly simpler to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ComplexListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html) as follows:

```
data = Join[Thread[{0, f /@ {0, 1}}], Thread[{0, g /@ {0, 1}}]];
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange};

clp1 = ComplexListPlot[data,  
     PlotStyle -> (Directive[Arrowheads[Large], AbsoluteThickness[3], #] & /@ colors),
     Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {-.3, 0}, PlotRange -> All] /. {Point -> Nothing, Line -> Arrow};

clp2 = ComplexListPlot[Join[Callout[f @ #, HoldForm[f @ #]] & /@ {0, 1}, 
    Callout[g @ #, HoldForm[g @ #]] & /@ {0, 1}]] /. Point -> Nothing;

Show[clp1, clp2]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to specify a color for each of the arrows?

Comment: @George, you can try something like `PlotStyle -> (Directive[Arrowheads[Large], AbsolutePointSize[0], AbsoluteThickness[3], #]&/@ {Red, Green, Blue, Orange})`

Comment: Last question: is there a way to add the labels "f[0]", "f[1]", etc to the arrows, and expand the axis so that all arrows are guaranteed to be visible?

Comment: @George, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

(* Use all 3 imaginary elements of the 4d quaternion for the Arrow, reserving the first element as 0, or to represent some other quantity, such as color. You must load the Quaternion Package with

<< "Quaternions`" *)

```
<< "Quaternions`"


q = Quaternion[0, 1, 2, 3];

arrowFromQuaternion[quaternion_Quaternion] :=  Module[{a, b, c}, {a, b, c} = Rest[List @@ quaternion];

Graphics3D[{Purple, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}}], PointSize[Large],Point[{a, b, c}]},Axes -> True]];
arrowFromQuaternion[q]
```