# Complex map of $W(z^2)W( \frac{1}{z})$

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the function$$W(z^2)W\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$$ in Desmos 3D, where $W(z)$ is the product log function and $z=x+iy$. You can check out my related Math.SE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831713/how-do-i-plot-wz2w1-z-where-wz-is-the-product-log-function-and-z-xy).

When I plugged the function into Wolfram Alpha (substituting in $z=x+iy$), I noticed one of the outputs labeled a "complex map", as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUwV.png):

[image]

I managed to plot the graph on the right using:

```
ComplexContourPlot[
  {Re[ProductLog[z^2] ProductLog[1/z]], Im[ProductLog[z^2] ProductLog[1/z]]},
  {z, 10}
]
```

[image]

How would I recreate the graph on the left? It also looks very interesting.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting your question more clearly?  Is it what you are looking for `ComplexContourPlot[{Re[z], Im[z]}, {z, 10}]`? Or perhaps would you rather make it more creative  like e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram/15643#15643)?

Comment: Since it's a map $z \mapsto W(z^2)W(1/z)$, the grid on the left should be `ComplexContourPlot[{Re[z], Im[z]}, {z, 10}]`.  I'm not sure how the black lines are defined, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- We use `ParametricPlot` to plot the mapping `x+I*y -> ReIm[f[x+I*y]]`.
- We subdivide the original domain to `11x11` parts.
- 

```
f[z_] := ProductLog[z^2] ProductLog[1/z];
plots = Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
    ParametricPlot[#, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
     Mesh -> {Subdivide[-4, 4, 11], Subdivide[-4, 4, 11]}, 
     MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Opacity[1], Blue}, {Thick, Opacity[1], 
        Orange}}, PlotStyle -> None, Exclusions -> All, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, Frame -> False, 
     Axes -> False]] & /@ {ReIm[z], ReIm[f[z]]}
GraphicsRow[plots]
```

[image]

- To plot the black lines.

```
{f1, f2, f3, f4} = {BSplineFunction[{{.15, -4}, {.15, -.6}}], 
  BSplineFunction[{{.15, 4}, {.15, .6}}], 
  BSplineFunction[{{-2.8, 0.1}, {-.1, 0.1}, {-.3, .12}, {-.15, .2}}], 
  BSplineFunction[{{-2.8, -0.1}, {-.1, -0.1}, {-.3, -.12}, {-.15, \
-.2}}]}; F = ReIm@*f@*({1, I} . # &);
plot1 = Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
   ParametricPlot[{f1@s, f2@s, f3@s, f4@s}, {s, 0, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Black}]];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[{F@*f1@s, F@*f2@s, F@*f3@s, F@*f4@s}, {s, 0, 
    1}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Black];
GraphicsRow@{Show[plots[[1]], plot1], Show[plots[[2]], plot2]}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the black lines? What do they represent?

Comment: @MarcoB  since `z==0` is a singular point,  we using the black lines as the trails to approaching `z==0`.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you. (+1)

Comment: @cvgmt very nice +1 :)